# How do I use Privoxy to replace images in the browsed pages?

Tags: raspbian

I am going to try [upside-down-ternet](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html) using `privoxy` on my proxy server.

My question is, how do I implement this on `privoxy`? My goal is to replace all ads with an image of my choice.

Comment: Someone with more rep, please add the privoxy and proxy tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the [quickstart](http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/quickstart.html) guide? They specifically have a section for exactly what you want.

> set-image-blocker - tells Privoxy what to display in place of an ad
>   image that has hit a block rule. For this to come into play, the URL
>   must match a block action somewhere in the configuration, and, it must
>   also match an handle-as-image action.
>
> The configuration options on what to display instead of the ad are:
>   pattern - a checkerboard pattern, so that an ad replacement is
>   obvious. This is the default.
>   blank - A very small empty GIF image is displayed. This is the so-called "invisible" > configuration option. 
>   http:// - A redirect to any image anywhere of the user's choosing
>   (advanced usage).

Tell us where your encountering a problem. Try flesh out the question as much as possible. Help us help you. Are you having a issue with the configuration? Is it not showing the picture? Can you not install `privoxy`?

Comment: I was able to install privoxy quite easily, and get the standard built-in filter replace some images with the gray box. Thank you for the link.

Comment: Awesome. Glad you came right. You know that you can also replace the ads with any image right? So like a lovely picture of Nicholas Cage ;)